# Lagrange Multiplier Method: Why is the Langragian function defined as $f(x,y)+\lambda \cdot g(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

**Edit:** As AlexR points out in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392280/lagrange-multiplier-method-why-is-the-langragian-function-defined-as-fx-y-l#comment2834585_1392307) comment, there is no mathematical reason behind defining the Lagrangian, except because it makes the Lagrange Multiplier Method easier to memorize. I find this confusing; for me, it is easier to find the critical values of the system of equations.

---

I still haven't found an explanation why is the Lagrange function defined as:

$$\Lambda(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y)+\lambda \cdot g(x,y)$$

Every author doesn't explain the procedure and I don't think is necessary to learn Lagrangian Mechanics to understand the formula, some examples:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Interpretation_of_the_Lagrange_multipliers):

> To incorporate these conditions into one equation, we introduce an auxiliary function
>
> [image]

[The Idea Shop](http://www.the-idea-shop.com/article/215/understanding-why-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-works):

> Now, if we're clever we can write a single equation that will capture this idea. This is where the familiar Lagrangian equation comes in:
>
> $L=f-\lambda(g-c)$

[Lagrange Multipliers Without Permanent Scarring by Dan Kein](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Eklein/papers/lagrange-multipliers.pdf):

> We can compactly represent both equations at once by writing the Lagrangian:
>
> $\Lambda(x,\lambda)=f(x)-\lambda g(x)$

The list goes on, the thing is that "Lagrangian" seems to have different meanings depending on the context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_%28disambiguation%29

So in this context, What does "Lagrangian function" means, and **what are the steps to get to that function**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The book "Mathematics for Economists" by Carl P. Simon and Lawrence Blume, p. 413 - 417 gives a nice explanation.

Comment: The Lagrangian $L:=f-\lambda g$ is a purely formal device without any intuitive geometrical or physical content. The essential point is the following: In a conditionally stationary point $x$ we necessarily have $\nabla f(x)=\lambda\nabla g(x)$ for some $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$, whereby this latter equation can be "explained intuitively".

Comment: @NigelOvermars, Nope, it does the same thing: "There is a convenient way of writing this system (6). Form the Lagrangian Function" I really dont understand how the author can summarise a system of three equations with three unknowns into a simple  function where the partial derivatives suddenly disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at, but I think this maybe helpful to you:

The intuition is that an extreme point of $f(x)$ under the condition $g(x) = 0$ must satisfy $g(x) = 0$ and $\nabla_\nu f(x) = 0$ for any direction $\nu$ tangential to the candidate set $\{g(x) = 0\}$. If this were not the case, we could go a small, positive distance along $\nabla_\nu f$ (or $-\nabla_\nu f$) to improve the function value without missing the constraint. Write these two below each other and get
$$\pmatrix{\nabla f + \lambda \nabla g\\g}(x) = 0$$
This however is the $z$-gradient of $f + \lambda g$ if we write $z = (x,\lambda)$.

It turns out that this in fact is the necessary condition for a constrained minimisation (or maximisation).

Comment: That's not quite right: you don't have $\nabla f(x)=0$, you have $\nabla f(x) \cdot u=0$ for every $u$ which is a direction tangent to the surface $g(x)=0$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that's right. Let me fix this.

Comment: What are the steps to get to the Lagrangian function?

Comment: @JaneSmith It's already shown in the above: the two conditions $\nabla_x f = \lambda \nabla_x g$ (which says "the gradient of $f$ is parallel to the gradient of $g$", hence the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to the level set of $g$) and $g(x)=0$ can be combined into $\nabla_z(f+\lambda g)=0$, where $z=(x,\lambda)$.

Comment: @JaneSmith Write down the necessary optimality conditions and notice that they can be written as the stationary points of $\Lambda(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda g(x)$. If you want a proof of that, ask for a proof of the Lagrangian multiplier theorem. Else, you should try to make your problem more clear since I don't know what exactly you're asking for.

Comment: >stationary points Do you mean saddle points?

Comment: @JaneSmith No, I mean stationary points. These can be any of local minimum, local maximum or saddle point.

Comment: @JaneSmith The intuition was captured nicely by AlexR: if the gradient of $f$ is not parallel to the gradient of $g$, then you can follow a direction $\nu$ which is tangent to the surface and thereby cause $f$ to (in the maximization case) increase. But in reality you do not go in the direction of $\nu$ and then stop: you go in the direction of $\nu$ and then project back to the surface. Going in the direction of $\nu$ (a short enough distance) will increase $f$; ensuring that projecting back does not decrease $f$ too much takes some additional work.

Comment: @Ian, I'm not asking for the intuition behind the Lagrange Method, my question are: What does "Lagrangian function" means, and what are the steps to get to that function? All the links I posted explain the concept very well.

Comment: @JaneSmith Both AlexR and I already said that: the "meaningful" conditions are $\nabla_x f = \lambda \nabla_x g$ and $g=0$. It is just a convenient observation that these two conditions can be combined into $\nabla_z L = 0$ where $L$ is the Lagrangian and $z=(x,\lambda)$.

Comment: @JaneSmith What do you mean by "Steps to get there"? What "Lagrangian function" means is rather simple: It's a definition. Given a problem
$$\min_x f(x) \mid g(x) = 0$$
or
$$\max_x f(x) \mid g(x) = 0$$
the Lagrangian function is _defined_ as
$$\Lambda (x,\lambda) := f(x) + \lambda g(x)$$

Comment: @AlexR, thats exactly why I was asking for: Why is the  Lagrangian function is defined as
Λ(x,λ):=f(x)+λg(x)

Comment: @JaneSmith Well because it is defined in such a way that its critical points are candidates for the optimization problem at hand. You are walking in circles with your question...

Comment: @AlexR Well no, ∇f(x)=λ∇g(x) is the object function and g(x)=0 the constraint, but when writing the Lagrangian the gradients "disappear"  how is this possible?

Comment: @JaneSmith Because the gradient of the Lagrangian is (up to a sign convention) $(\nabla_x f + \lambda \nabla_x g,g)$

Comment: @JaneSmith Because you don't solve for $\Lambda(x,\lambda) = 0$. The gradient just moves "outside" to $\Lambda$. Your two equations can be combined into one completely equivalent. $\nabla_{(x,\lambda)} \Lambda(x,\lambda) = 0$. What is the real question??

Comment: @JaneSmith Not quite yet. The Lagrangian doesn't include the gradient, but you only work with the gradient of the Lagrangian.

Comment: @AlexR, Why go through the trouble of defining a new function when I just can take the gradient of the object function and the constraint function?

Comment: @JaneSmith At least for me, the definition of the Lagrangian is a lot easier to _remember_ even after years. There is no mathematical reason behind this, though.

Comment: @AlexR, Thanks for your help. I'm gonna accept  your answer and add an edit to my answer to bring attention to this comment.

Comment: @JaneSmith It's not quite true that there is *no* mathematical significance. If $f$ and $g$ are both convex and we adopt the positive sign convention, then the Lagrangian is convex, and its critical point is a minimum. (Analogously, if $f$ and $g$ are both concave and we take the negative sign convention, then the Lagrangian is concave, and its critical point is a maximum.) Thus we have converted a constrained minimization problem into an unconstrained minimization problem for a convex objective function.

Comment: @JaneSmith (Cont.) This is powerful for certain purposes; for instance, it permits the formulation of "interior point methods", which allow us to numerically compute solutions of a constrained problem without actually enforcing the constraint throughout the computation.

Comment: @Ian Isn't the Lagragian derived from the system of equations?, positive or negative depends on how you define the object function. Also, a quick trawl through Google Books does not reveal an overwhelming majority in favor of either sign, there seems to be a difference between economics conventions, which tend to favor −λ, and mathematics conventions favoring λ. In most examples of multivariate analysis the obtained λ-value is thrown away anyway; it has no geometric meaning.

Comment: @JaneSmith You can pick the sign convention for $\lambda$ either way, it doesn't change the solution in $x$. You're wrong that it has no geometric meaning. Under the $-$ sign convention, the Lagrange multiplier is the derivative of the optimal value of $f$ with respect to a change in the value of the constraint. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_price for an economics interpretation.